# SML - Using map to return combined results

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have these functions:

```
fun IsDivisible(t, t2) = if t mod t2 > 0 then true else false;

fun IsDivisibleFilter(ts, t) = List.filter(fn x => IsDivisible(x, t)) ts;

fun IsDivisibleMap(ts, ts2) = map(fn x => IsDivisibleFilter(ts, x)) ts2;
```

**IsDivisibleMap** - Takes two lists of ints, *ts*, and *ts2*, and returns a list containing those elements of *ts* that are indivisible by any elements in *ts2*.

E.g. IsDivisibleMap([10,11,12,13,14],[3,5,7]) should return [11,13].

The way I have it now it is returning a list of lists, where each list is the result for each number in *ts2*

E.g. IsDivisibleMap([10,11,12,13,14],[3,5,7]) is returning [10,11,13,14][11,12,13,14][10,11,12,13]

How can I return the result that I am looking for while still using map and filter wherever possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various problems here with terminology; I'd like to begin by addressing those.

First, the name `IsDivisibleMap` is not a good name for two reasons:

1. Based on the description of the function, it is a *filter*, not a map. That is, given an input list, it removes elements from that list which do not satisfy a predicate.
2. The elements produced by this function are *indivisible* by all elements of the second input.

Based on these considerations, I'd like to call the function `IsIndivisibleFilter` instead. I will also change the name `IsDivisible` to `IsIndivisible`.

Second, in your description of the function, you say that it should return a list containing those elements of `ts` that are indivisible by **any** elements in `ts2`. However, I think what you meant is: "return a list containing those elements of `ts` that are indivisible by **all** elements in `ts2`"

---

Now, back to the main problem. For each element of `ts`, we need to check that it is indivisible by all of the elements of `ts2`. There is a nice function called `List.all` which checks if all elements of a list satisfy some predicate. So to check a particular element `t` of `ts`, we could do:

```
fun IsIndivisibleByAll (t, ts2) = 
  List.all (fn t2 => IsIndivisible (t, t2)) ts2
```

Now we can implement the original function by filtering according to this predicate:

```
fun IsIndivisibleFilter (ts, ts2) =
  List.filter (fn t => IsIndivisibleByAll (t, ts2)) ts
```

---

Finally, I'd like to mention that you could clean up this implementation quite a bit with proper currying. Here's how I would implement it:

```
fun IsIndivisible t t2 = (t mod t2 > 0)
fun IsIndivisibleByAll ts2 t = List.all (IsIndivisible t) ts2
fun IsIndivisibleFilter (ts, ts2) = List.filter (IsIndivisibleByAll ts2) ts
```

Comment: Fantastic! List.all is exactly what I needed. Thank you.